# mysql multiple join and retrieving only one record from two inner join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in stuck in a query. Here is my current query.

```
SELECT products.product_id, products.product_title,
    package_category_products.PCP_id,
    product_images.PI_file_name
FROM package_category_products
LEFT JOIN products ON products.product_id = package_category_products.PCP_product_id

-- BEGIN MARKED CODE
LEFT JOIN product_inventories on product_inventories.PI_product_id = products.product_id
INNER JOIN product_images on product_images.PI_product_id = product_inventories.PI_product_id
    AND product_images.PI_color = product_inventories.PI_color_id
-- END MARKED CODE

WHERE PCP_package_id = 17
AND PCP_package_category_id = 3
AND product_status ='active'
```

This query currently return redundant data. I want to use a sub query at the marked code to return only one record from this two table after joining. So that I will avoid redundant data and note that I need only one record for each product.

Comment: you could use `GROUP BY products.product_id`

Comment: One of three things, use `distinct` because you're not returning all the columns which uniquely identify the records for each table. use `group by` for each of the columns returned for the same reason. or one of your joins is missing a join criteria which is resulting in an unexpected carteasean.  table structures and sample data showing the problem from each table.... any one of these three possibilities exist.  I personally avoid distinct as group by just seems cleaner to me as I have to make a conscious effort about what I'm grouping  which may lead me to uncover a bad join...

Answer (score 1):

Replace "SELECT" by "SELECT DISTINCT":

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.product_id, a.product_title, d.PCP_id, c.PI_file_name

FROM package_category_products as d
LEFT JOIN products as a
ON a.product_id = d.PCP_product_id 

LEFT JOIN product_inventories as b on b.PI_product_id = a.product_id 

INNER JOIN product_images  as c
ON c.PI_product_id = b.PI_product_id AND c.PI_color = b.PI_color_id

WHERE PCP_package_id = 17 AND PCP_package_category_id = 3 AND product_status ='active'
```